# How I See my Result in Select from Where MYSQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, i try to call my data from table database mysql , but didn't see any result. always go to else , not go to the process. what would i do?

```html
<?php
require('connectDB.php');
                 $nama = $_GET['nama'];
                 echo $nama;
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM pesan
                    WHERE nama = '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $nama) . "%'
                    
                    ";
              $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
              $baris = mysqli_num_rows($results);
              

              if (!$results) {
               die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
              }

              if ( $baris > 0) {
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
               ?>
                <h3>Nama Mobil : <?php echo $row['mobil'] ?></h3>
                <h3>ID Pembelian : <?php echo $row['id']; ?></h3>
                <h3>Nama anda : <?php echo $row['nama']; ?></h3>
                <h3>Alamat : <?php echo $row['alamat']; ?></h3> 
                <h3>Tanggal Masuk : <?php echo $row['tgl_masuk']; ?></h3>
              <?php
               }
              }else{
               echo "error";
              }
              ?>
```

What wrong with my code?
Thanks!

im sorry , this is my ConnectDB.php , i include in my html.

```html
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dealermobil');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error());
}

// $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_login;charset=utf8mb4','root','');
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$connection` defined? Try printing '$connection' variable.

Comment: `... WHERE name = '%" ...`? It should be `... WHERE name LIKE '%" ...`

Comment: Still Error @RajdeepPaul

Comment: Im sorry , i just editted now. See Again @user3025122

Comment: `mysql_error()` ? You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` APIs. RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Also, check how many rows are returned from the `SELECT` query, do `var_dump($baris);`.

Comment: when i try var_dump($baris); got result int(0). its that true?

Comment: It means your query is getting executed just fine, at least with the value you're getting from the `$_GET` superglobal. Now do `echo $query;` and check whether the query is correct or not. If it is, then execute this query on MySQL console and see what result you're getting there.

Comment: Did you `echo $baris;` ?

Comment: when i try echo $query got no result  @RajdeepPaul

Comment: i try echo $baris didnt see anything @Amir

Comment: what is result of `echo $nama;`?

Comment: echo $nama for debugging , print method GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection check and result check is incorrect.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dealermobil');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Also

```
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$baris = mysqli_num_rows($results);


if (!$results) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Mr. Amir , but i got answer by myself. can i ask how to connect a table database to b table database (ex mobil table to pesan table)

Comment: You should use join command `SELECT ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 on ... WHERE ...` please refer to documents

Answer (score 0):

use this you are using `=` it should be `LIKE` when you are trying to search a field in database.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `pesan` WHERE `nama` LIKE '%". mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $nama) ."%'";
```

Comment: i try it but no result mr. Kunal